# From this Cassandara table, I need to create a table such that it stores data of last 2,5,10,30 and 180 days and maintains automatically day by day

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra

```
+----+----------+-------+
|type|date      |count  |
+----+----------+-------+
|Typ1|2022-02-14|2      |
|Typ1|2022-02-12|0      |
|Typ2|2022-02-10|1      |
|Typ2|2022-02-01|1      |
|Typ2|2022-01-20|1      |
|Typ2|2022-01-15|1      |
|Typ2|2022-01-05|1      |
+----+----------+-------+
```

This table gets appended whenever the new row comes up. So now I need to maintain a new table such that it stores the data of last 2,5,10,30 and 180 days. For reference, this might be the new table structure:

```
+-------+-------+
|Days   |count  |
+-------+-------+
|Last2  |2      |
|Last5  |3      |
|Last10 |3      |
|Last30 |6      |
|Last180|7      |
+----+----------+
```

I tried doing groupBy and count but doing this everyday is not good from 'processing-time' point of view because the Table-1 may contain millions of rows and doing groupBy everytime doesn't feel like a good solution to me.

What could be the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing the populating/updating new table via application at the same time any new record is inserted in first table if you intend to keep 5 keys as mentioned in example. Better solution could be using spark/spark-cassandra-connector for reading data from first table and processing in memory the data you want at runtime.